# Callan-Symanzik equation renormalization for QED

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, renormalization

On page 416 of Peskin and Schroeder, the book says to find the explicit expressions for the [Callan-Symanzik functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callan%E2%80%93Symanzik_equation) of QED, we must write expressions for the counterterms $\delta_1,\delta_2,\delta_3$. However here we must now reevaluate for massless fermions and renormalization at $-M^2$ where $M$ is the renormalization scale.

My question is: what would be precise renormalization condition here? For QED on page 332 we have using on-shell renormalization conditions for massive fermions
$$\tag{10.40} \Sigma(\not{p}=m)=0\\ \frac{d}{d\not p}|_{\not p=m}=0\\ \Pi(q^2=0)=0\\ -ie\Gamma^\mu(p'-p=0)=-ie\gamma^\mu.$$

What should we replace (10.40) by?

Answer (score 4):

There are several conditions, but I introduce mass- independent renormalization (MIR), since it has some advantages(see below). On the other hand, the conditions that you wrote in your question is called as on-shell conditions. One essential idea of MIR is to regularize a theory as a function of the ( in this case fermion’s) bare mass parameter $m$. So, I explicitly write the mass dependence below. For example, you can take a following conditions:
$$\Sigma(p^2=0,m^2)|_{m^2=0}=0,$$
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial m^2}\Sigma(p^2=0,m^2)|_{m^2=-M^2}=0,$$
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial \not p}\Sigma(p^2=0,m^2)|_{m^2=-M^2}=0 $$
$$\Gamma^\mu(p’-p=0, m^2)|_{m^2=-M^2}=\gamma^\mu$$
$$\Pi(p^2=0,m^2)|_{m^2=-M^2}=0 $$

First condition is important because it states that if we don’t have massive particle our theory must be massless after the renormalization process. Second to forth conditions are simply states that the divergence of the theory is subtracted at the renormalization point to make our theory finite.

Finally, I give some comments:

1. The famous $\overline{MS}$ scheme is one of the most famous example of MIR, but they impose renormalization condition at each order of perturbation instead of imposing  it to quantum effective action. In this case, the renormalization point is $\mu$ which appeared to use a dimensional reguralization.
2. If the theory is massless, the Gell-man Low equation is convenient. In this case, we don’t need to consider MIR because one reason for considering MIR is that for theories with a mass parameter, if the renormalization constant depends on mass, the RG equation becomes unnecessarily complicated. (When MIR is imposed, the renormalization constant is generally independent of mass.) Therefore, if the theory is massless, there is little benefit in considering MIR.